# Android Camera SurfaceView disappears when placing an ImageView overlay on top of it

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, camera, surfaceview

I used to have a nice little fragment that loaded the camera in a frame (An image overlayed on top in a frame layout). After doing some refactoring to my code( which I have gone over Incessantly), I suddenly noticed that my camera didn't work.The SurfaceView that was supposed to show the camera was blank.

Over the last four hours, I added null checks and breakpoints everywhere. I could not find the source of the breakage. So then I swapped out most of my code for a line by line copy of the CommonsWare Camera example. The main difference is that my version was in a Fragment instead of an activity.

I understood most(if not all) of it while re-implementing it, and made it fit my current fragment based system. While it did not fix my bug, after a while I discovered that moving my SurfaceView above my ImageView worked. However, it did not provide the intended overlay effect as the frame was now effectively over the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...Until I found that I had set the fragment container to a Hardware layer and forgot to return it to normal.

Beware this line:

```
findViewById(R.id.fragment_container).setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

It messes with camera rendering.

---

Hopefully this helps some other poor soul.